# I would like to horizontally center the text in a table but also align it to the left [HTML/CSS]

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of tables on my site and I'm looking of ways to improve the appearance of them.

This is currently what my table looks like (http://prntscr.com/gpa4w6)

I'm trying to achieve this look (http://prntscr.com/gpa52q)

As you can see in the above picture, the text is centered in the column but also aligned to the left. How would I go around doing that?

```
echo "<tr><td>".$data['BanID']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$data['Name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$data['Reason']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$data['Date']."</td></tr>";}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, share the HTML and CSS for the table,if possible a working snippet showing the issue and what needs to be fixed!

Comment: Share the code or link me to that website please?

Comment: I don't think the left-aligned text is really "centered". I think the `<td>`s just have some padding applied.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP and has everything to do with your HTML and CSS, so please post a [mcve] showing us what you've tried and include the rendered HTML with the CSS.

Comment: Answer is correct, that's not centered. Just add left-padding.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like it could be achieved if you add a left padding while keeping your alignment left.

Answer (score 0):

Your table must have thead, tbody and tfoot. Then format thead th elements with align center, and tbody tr elements with align left.

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Content</th>
         <th>Content</th>
         <th>Content</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Content</th>
         <th>Content</th>
         <th>Content</th>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And your CSS makes the magic:

```
table > thead > tr > th { text-align: center;}
table > tbody > tr > td { text-align: left;  }
```